# Download, save to local storage, then display image in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to download an image from a url, save that image to local storage, and then display the stored image in an Image View. Is there a shared PCL library that can do all of this? If not, what would be the best approach for this using Dependency Services in iOS and Android?

Comment: FFImageLoading would be a good bet. You can just hand it an URL and it will cache and display it for you.

Comment: @Cheesebaron FFImageLoading is great for caching images, but I need to save the image to file on the device's local storage

Comment: Well the image is saved in local storage in FFImageLoading

Comment: @Cheesebaron I didn't explain myself right. I want my users to log in initially, and all their data (including images) be downloaded from a rest api and saved to their device. From this point on I want the app to work without an internet connection. So after this point, any images that are displayed are actually files saved on the local storage, and aren't gotten from loading urls. Would I be right in saying that FFImageLoading wouldn't work for this purpose?

Comment: Technically it would work just fine. You can give it your own instance of HttpClient if you need headers for auth etc. However, there are plugins which allow you to do File manipulations in PCL. You could combine that with HttpClient and you have what you need.